# Microsoft Graph non-interactive login for Native application

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I have a native C# .NET Console application which is used by customers to pull user license assignments from Graph for Office 365.  I've implemented interactive authentication and admin consent, which is working.  I also need to be able to script the application so it can run on a schedule, so want to authenticate non-interactively, providing the credentials when the application runs.

For this I'm using the following call:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/token

resource=https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.com
&client_id={_clientId}
&grant_type=password
&username={username}
&password={password}
```

Once the application is authorized for the user or via Admin Consent, this works for me against our tenant.

But for a customer I'm working with, this does not work.  (*The customer has two-factor authentication enabled, so I'm not sure if that is affecting it.  Interactive authentication works for them, but Admin Consent, although it returns 'admin_consent=True', does not seem to be working, the user is still prompted to authorize the app, which they cannot do as they are not a global admin, but the global admin can authorize themselves.*)

What is the best/correct (official/unofficial) way to authenticate non-interactively with Graph for Native applications.  (All documentation I have read so far says it not supported for Native applications, and push towards the interactive authentication.)

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should *definitely* avoid using the `password` grant. You're exposing yourself to a huge liability risk by storing the username and password. It is far too easily compromised.

For service/daemon scenarios, you should use the `client_credentials` grant. Once you receive Admin Consent it will allow you to retrieve a token without a user involved (or in context).

The documentation for this can be found at:

- [Get access without a user](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/auth_v2_service)
- [Azure Active Directory v2.0 and the OAuth 2.0 client credentials flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-v2-protocols-oauth-client-creds)

Comment: Thanks Marc.  The app is a console app that is run from the customer's site, and the credentials are stored encrypted locally.  client_credentials for service/daemon scenarios does not seem to be supported by Native applications according to the documentation I have read, and indeed did not work when I tried to use them using a pre-shared key.  Text from one article for example: "Note When registering the app in Azure AD, you must select the Web Application and/or Web API type, as app-only permissions are not available for native client applications."

Comment: I'm not sure where you read this, but this isn't entirely accurate (or at least out of context is reads as inaccurate). The Client Credentials Grant is supported by both the [Azure AD v2 Endpoint and Microsoft Graph](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-v2-protocols-oauth-client-creds). Your scenario is _exactly_ that this grant was designed for, service/daemon applications.

Comment: Thanks Marc.  When I tried this last time, I was able to get an authentication token, but could not use it to get results from Graph, something about unable to find service account.  I'll try it again and see how I get on.  I did also read that the client password is not supported by Native clients, only the public/private keys, do you know if that is the case?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "client password" but the `client_credentials` grant is supported (and almost exclusively used for) native daemon/service applications.

Comment: Hi Marc, I'm using the 'Application Secret' with the `client_credentials` grant again, and again, although I successfully retrieve an auth token, when I attempt to call Graph methods such as `https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users`, I get the error: `code: Authorization_IdentityNotFound` `message: The identity of the calling application could not be established.`  I'm simply calling the methods the same way I do when I have a token from a user authentication, a GET call to the URL with the Bearer token as the AuthenticationHeaderValue.

Comment: I think I have figured out what was wrong.  I was using the endpoint `https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token`, which does return an auth token, but produces the `Authorization_IdentityNotFound` error when querying Graph.  I instead switched to using `https://login.microsoftonline.com/MYTENANT.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/v2.0/token` and I get the token, but can now also retrieve results from Graph.  It seems `common` as a tenant identifier cannot be used for APP only `client_credentials` grant.

Comment: That's correct, you cannot use Common with Client Credentials because there isn't a user involved. Without a user we don't have the ability to discover which tenant you want to work against.